# venv/bin/activate:48: command not found: already "Mac m1" python Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, localhost, virtualenv

when activate my virtualenv in my local get this error in my "Mac m1" python Django

```
venv/bin/activate:48: command not found: already
```

when activate my virtualenv in my local get this error in my "Mac m1" python Django

Comment: how are you activating it?

Comment: _when activate my virtualenv_ Show us the exact command you used.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong command, you have to use the `source` keyword.

- The `source` keyword is used to execute the script within the current shell environment, ensuring that the virtual environment's settings take effect.

Use this command instead:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```